# get height of a Widget using its GlobalKey in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am struggling getting the height of a Widget using its GlobalKey.
the function that is getting the height is called after the Layout is rendered to make sure the context is available but key.currentState and also key.currentContext still returns null.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new TestPageState();
}

class TestPageState extends State<TestPage>{
  final TestWidget testWidget = new TestWidget();

  @override
  initState() {
    //calling the getHeight Function after the Layout is Rendered
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => getHeight());

    super.initState();
  }

  void getHeight(){
    final GlobalKey key = testWidget.key;

    //returns null:
    final State state = key.currentState;
    //returns null:
    final BuildContext context = key.currentContext;

    //Error: The getter 'context' was called on null.
    final RenderBox box = state.context.findRenderObject();

    print(box.size.height);
    print(context.size.height);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: testWidget,
    );
  }
}

class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  Key get key => new GlobalKey<TestWidgetState>();

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new TestWidgetState();
}

class TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Text("Test", style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to assign that key to a widget using `super` in the widget constructor. Not add it as a field.
That `Key` also must be constant.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new TestPageState();
}

class TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  final key = new GlobalKey<TestWidgetState>();

  @override
  initState() {
    //calling the getHeight Function after the Layout is Rendered
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => getHeight());

    super.initState();
  }

  void getHeight() {
    //returns null:
    final State state = key.currentState;
    //returns null:
    final BuildContext context = key.currentContext;

    //Error: The getter 'context' was called on null.
    final RenderBox box = state.context.findRenderObject();

    print(box.size.height);
    print(context.size.height);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new TestWidget(key: key),
    );
  }
}

class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  TestWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new TestWidgetState();
}

class TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Text(
        "Test",
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The above code gives this error
//Error: The getter 'context' was called on null.

Comment: @AsadJamil If you try to run it via `runApp(TestPage());`, it will return this error, but if you wrap TestPage in MediaQuery and Directionality widgets (with data and textDirection parameters supplied), or a MaterialApp or WidgetsApp widget, it should run (or at least does for me).

Comment: @AsadJamil yet, in your example the key is not constant.

Comment: I get compile error: The getter 'size' isn't defined for the type 'RenderObject'

Answer (score 4):

Define your constructor like this:

`const MyWidget(GlobalKey key) : super(key:key);`.

The framework stores the `BuildContext` and `State` object in the `Widget.key` field which is passed into the object by constructor instead of an arbitary `key` field.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes better approach is to use LayoutBuilder. In this case the code looks like

```
return LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    print('Available container sizes - ${constraints.maxWidth} - ${constraints.maxHeight}');
    return Container(
      child: new Text(
        "Test",
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

This approach gives info dynamically, often useful with animations.